# Google Analytics speed so high for an only redirect page

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, google-pagespeed

I have a page with google ananlytics (GA) code tracking and a small javascript code block to detect user os (android or ios) to redirect to google play or ios.

The problem is by GA tracking, speed of this page is so slow (about 5.5 s to load), it even slower than other page with full of content (4s).

I tested and see this page redirect immediately and no delay so I expect GA track this page only 1-2 second to load.

Any body encouter this problem and help me some suggestion to improve this.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics site speed measurements are sampled - 1% by default ([reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1205784?hl=en)).

If you want a more accurate measurement of page speeds, [set the sample rate to 100%](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try and measure it now.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the avg speed for this download page still high (4.3s). Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It may then actually be an issue with load times on that particular page. Even though your tests show it's loading fast, other users may not be experiencing the same. Try segmenting the page load speeds by geography, device type, network, browser, etc, to see if you can find a culprit